# Как определить позицию курсора в поле типа number?

Tags: javascript

> Согласно спецификации [WHATWG forms](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#concept-input-apply) свойства `selectionStart`,
>   `selectionEnd` и метод `setSelectionRange` применяются только к элементам
>   `input` c типами `text`, `search`, `URL`, `tel` и `password`.

Comment: [this is impossible with `<input type="number" />`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25371702/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy Т.е. никаких способов вообще не существует что ли?

Comment: Это, в принципе, и не нужно, для этого типа. Для чего тебе нужно узнавать позицию курсора?

Comment: @Grundy Мне нужно. Такой проект.

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка проектирования. В любом случае решается заменой типа на `text`. Не исключена также, [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/186999)